# Static Site Deployment in AWS S3 with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am trying to set up a static website that has been configured to use index.html default documents.  I have the following bucket policy set up in S3:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.risendeadmc.com/*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The 2nd step is I created a CloundFront distribution to distribute this S3 content.

Issue 1: Sub folders are still accessible by CDN domain name but index.html no longer load as default for document and hitting folder causing a content download.

I then set up a A record Alias to the CDN distribution in Route53 and now nothing resolves with a 403 Forbidden error no matter what I use.

Any configuration advise to resolve would be greatly appreciated.

What I am looking for is the ability to use my domain set up in Route53 to point to the CloudFront Distribution to provide access (with index.html default) content access.

I would like to keep root and sub folder default access points to non file suffixed endpoint reference:

http://mydomain.com/root

or

http://mydomain.com/root/sub/subroot

rather than address index.html

Comment: While setting up Cloudfront distribution, did you specify what cnames you will be using for this distribution?

Comment: I don't believe that I did.

Comment: You will have to specify that. Otherwise Cloudfront servers won't know which distribution your domain is referring to (reading from DNS for every request is painful). Edit your distribution, add the domain name to your distribution. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#CreatingCNAME

Comment: So I added the CNAME and it does recognize the domain entry now, but I still seem to have lost the default document setup in sub directories where index.html come up without having ot reference the file name explicity?

Comment: As @imperalix says, change the distribution origin from bucket name to website end point. To do this though, first you will need to setup "static website hosting" for your bucket. This will give you a URL something like: bucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. now edit the CF distribution and change the origin name. Instead of selecting the bucket, enter the website URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to make sure that you are setting your default root object in Amazon S3 and that your origin is the S3 Website endpoint.

Example origin: www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html